# EF Core declares two foreign key from different table in a single table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I'm using EF core with Fluent api and I got three tables (DomainObject is for the Ids) :

```
public class Category : DomainObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Deadline : DomainObject
{
    public Account Tiers { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_On { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction : DomainObject
{
    public Account Payee { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateProcessed { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see Transaction and Deadline contains a Category foreign key.

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Deadline>()
  .HasOne(e => e.Account)
  .WithMany(e => e.Deadlines)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder
  .Entity<Transaction>()
  .HasOne(e => e.Account)
  .WithMany(e => e.Transactions)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

If create a Transaction with a "Food" Category and then I try to create a Deadline with a "Food" Category I got :

> InnerException = {"SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Category.Id'."}

This method create a deadline and update in database :

```
public async Task<ManagementResult> CreateDeadline(User user, Account account, string tiers, string type, double amount, Category category, string notes, DateTime next_Deadline, string frequency, int nbOccurences)
    {
        ManagementResult result = ManagementResult.Success;

        if (amount <= 0)
        {
            result = ManagementResult.IncorrectAmount;
        }
        if (category == null)
        {
            result = ManagementResult.CategoryMissing;
        }
        if (frequency == null)
        {
            result = ManagementResult.FrequencyMissing;
        }
        if (result == ManagementResult.Success)
        {
            user.Accounts.Remove(account);
            Deadline deadline = new Deadline()
            {
                Tiers = tiers,
                Account = account,
                Type = type,
                Amount = amount,
                Category = category,
                Notes = notes,
                Next_Deadline = next_Deadline,
                Frequency = frequency,
                NbOccurences = nbOccurences,
                Status = "En cours",
                Created_On = DateTime.Now
            };
            if (account.Deadlines == null)
            {
                account.Deadlines = new List<Deadline>();
            }
            // Updating ICollection inside the user object
            account.Deadlines.Add(deadline);
            user.Accounts.Add(account);
            
            // Here is where i get the Exception
            await _deadlineService.Create(deadline);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Then this is DeadlineDataService method :

```
    // Here is the create method who's called
    public async Task<Deadline> Create(Deadline entity)
    {
        return await _nonQueryDataService.Create(entity);
    }
```

And here's the NonQueryDataService method :

```
public async Task<T> Create(T entity)
    {
        using (BookkeepingDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            EntityEntry<T> createdResult = await context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return createdResult.Entity;
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You have to post your code

Comment: it's complicated because it's a big application, there is a lot of code but I will try

Comment: I mean the whole controller action where you trying to add the items

Comment: I think you insert a category with the same id... can you post Category Object value that you insert into new Deadline()? Or the complete code where you create category?

Comment: This is weird because there is no category creation here, Category are injected at the start of the application.
When you create a Deadline you have to asign an existing Category that you choose in a comboBox wich is related to a ICollection<Category>.
So EF is trying to save in database "child object" ?